# Is There anyone who knows what this piece of code does?

Tags: javascript, api

I am very new to javascript .. and my teacher provided us with this piece of code along with html and css file which on any date you enter gives you images of mars taken from ISS..
Would anyone care to explain what is happening inside the data: {} and how to get such API URL'S? I mean from where do we get that?

```
var input_box=$('#div-date input');
var button=$('#div-button button');
var container2=$('#container2');
button.click(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos",
        data:
        {
            earth_date:parseInt(input_box.val().split('/')[2]).toString()+"- 
          "+parseInt(input_box.val().split('/')[1]).toString()+"- 
      "+parseInt(input_box.val().split('/')[0]).toString(),
            api_key:"zrVafsMHD8r1SC8mHyg91mnNguuzdIoPRXGD1BvS"
        },
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research (for instance, at https://api.jquery.com), read the descriptions of the methods, look at how the logic flows, etc. As a programmer, you read other people's code a **lot**. It's an important skill to develop. If you run into a *specific* part of the above you're having trouble with, post a question asking specifically about that part, saying what you've read and what you don't understand. Folks will be happy to help.

Comment: Not just https://api.jquery.com, but also MDN: [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: Side note: This...isn't very good code. Hopefully it's meant as an example of unnecessarily-hard-to-read code, but if not I wouldn't put much stock in any general coding advice you get from this teacher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ajax` method is a call to NASA endpoint where you are doing a `GET` call to the URL. I thinks this is clear.

Now, what does data?

`earth_date` is a value with the actual date parsed to a specific format. It get the date from the `input_box` with format `00/00/0000` and parse to format `0000-00-00`

`api_key` is the key you need to authenticate and get the data.

And `data` itself is the way to send variables into URL. So, your url looks like this:

`https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?earth_date=YOUR_DATE&api_key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Note that is compound by:
`url`+ `?earth_date` + `api_key`.

Updated to answer the question:

The API key is a way to secure the API.

An API key is a way to identify who is calling the endpoint. So only calls that have the API key will be able to reach the endpoint (or whatever the developer want).

Is an string generated by the owner so the only way to get the API key is NASA to give it to you. I suppose NASA give free API keys, but is not a "general string" or something like that. Every organization will secure their apis in a way, NASA provide api keys to reach his 'free' endpoints.

Comment: and could you tell me where we get the api key from? I dont even understand whats wriiten in the API given there.. so you just google it or? There are specefic sites for it?

Answer (score 0):

The code in the data transform the date format '30/12/2019' to '2019-12-30' since only the later format is valid for the request.

Comment: Same.. he started from basics.. but then he started going very vast and we students were like what the..